# Navigation using arrow keys inside DataGrid stucks

Tags: wpf, datagrid, .net-4.0, navigation

I am using DataGrid available in framework 4.0. In my grid, some of my cells are disabled as these cell are read only and user is not supposed to alter its value. (I can't make DataGrid column as ReadOnly because not all the values inside the column will be read only.) Now I'm seeing problem with navigation using the arrow keys due to this.

Whenever I'm using arrow keys and next cell to which focus is supposed to move after pressing arrow key is disabled then nothing happens and focus still retains within original cell. What I expect is, if DataGrid encounters disabled cell during navigation either it should jump to the next available cell (which is not disabled) or just allow navigation through disabled cell.

The least I expect is user shouldn't get stuck and can still move further using arrow keys.